# What rule of logic is this?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was reading a proof on proving associative law for XOR operator and came across these steps.

= (AB'C'+A'BC')+(A'+B)(A+B')C

= (AB'C'+A'BC')+(A'(A+B')+B(A+B'))C

= (AB'C'+A'BC')+(A'B' + AB)C

I understood what was happening up to this point, but don't understand how you get from step one to two, or two to three. Can someone please explain why/how you get to those steps in that order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the law of distribution: $X(Y+Z)=XY+XZ$ and $X+YZ=(X+Y)(X+Z)$

Also the identity laws: $X'X=0$ and $X+0=X$

$\begin{align}
\ldots &= (AB'C'+A'BC')+(A'+B)(A+B')C & \tag{1}
\\ & = (AB'C'+A'BC')+(A'\color{blue}{(A+B')}+B\color{blue}{(A+B')})C \tag{2}
\\ & =  (AB'C'+A'BC')+((\color{blue}{A'}A+\color{blue}{A'}B')+(\color{blue}{B}A+\color{blue}{B}B'))C \tag{2a}
\\ & =  (AB'C'+A'BC')+((\color{blue}{0}+A'B')+(BA+\color{blue}{0}))C \tag{2b}
\\ & =  (AB'C'+A'BC')+(A'B'+BA)C \tag{3}
\end{align}$

Can you see what's happening now?

Comment: Oh I see it now, thanks! I hadn't realized that in step two the statements in brackets were the same. I though that the A' and B where being pulled out of the separate statements somehow.